# Proving $K_2(A)=\frac{\sqrt{\max_i|\lambda_i(A^\top A)}|}{\sqrt{\min_i|\lambda_i(A^\top A)|}}$ without using singular values

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-methods, singular-values

In my notes the condition number of a non-singular rectangular matrix is defined as
$$K(A)=\|A\|\|A^{-1}\|$$

and the 2-norm of a rectangular matrix as: $$\|A\|_2=\sqrt{\max_i |\lambda_i(A^\top A)|}$$, with $\lambda_i(B) $ meaning i-th eigenvalue of B

**Then it gives the following formula for the condition number with respect to the 2-norm:
$$K_2(A)=\frac{\sqrt{\max_i|\lambda_i(A^\top A)}|}{\sqrt{\min_i|\lambda_i(A^\top A)|}}$$**

**I am trying to prove this formula.** I've seen online that they use singular values, but I think is not necessary .

**This is my proof:**

Using the definitions:

$K_2(A)=\|A\|_2\|A^{-1}\|_2 = \sqrt{\max_i|\lambda_i(A^\top A)|} \sqrt{\max_i|\lambda_i((A^{-1})^\top A^{-1})|}$.

So all I have too prove is that:

$\sqrt{\max_i|\lambda_i((A^{-1})^\top A^{-1})|}=1/\sqrt{\min_i|\lambda_i(A^\top A)|}$

If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of a non singular square matrix C with eigenvector $v$, then: $Cv=\lambda v$ so, since C is non singular: $v=\lambda C^{-1}v$ , so  $(1/\lambda)v= C^{-1}v$ , so $1/\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $C^{-1}$. So I have proven the eigenvalues of the inverse are the reciprocal of the eigenvalues. Using that:

$\sqrt{\max_i|\lambda_i((A^{-1})^\top A^{-1})|}=\sqrt{\max_i|\lambda_i(A A^\top)^{-1})|} = 1/\sqrt{\min_i|\lambda_i(A A^\top)|}$

Now $A A^\top $ is an square matrix and it is  invertible since A is invertible. So  $0$ is not an eigenvalue of $A A^\top$  .(Moreover it is symmetric so it has real eigenvalues if that is useful )

, but $A^T A$ and $AA^T $ have the same non-zero eigenvalues, since $ 0$ is not an eigenvalue they have the same eigenvalues so $1/\sqrt{\min_i|\lambda_i(A A^\top)|}= 1/\sqrt{\min_i|\lambda_i(A^\top A )|}$ which is what I needed to complete the proof

**What do you think, is it ok? If it is, why do people go through all the trouble of using the more complicated  singular values approach ?. If it is not correct, where is it wrong?**

Comment: With the information you have been given, your proof is valid. Depending on the audience you may wish to explicitly show that $AA^T$ and $A^TA$ have the same eigenvalues. The fundamental issue here is that you have not been given the core definition of a matrix norm or a condition number. You have been given formulas that are correct, but they do not contain the information included in the core definitions. The use of the singular value decomposition yields a proof that is slightly more complicated but one can also show that not all right-hand sides are equally problematic.

Comment: @CarlChristian Isn't the core definition of condition number the one I wrote? And the proven formula  the most general and valid only when  the matrix norm is the 2-norm? If I didn't get you wrong, why is this formula not the most general one when using the 2-norm?

Comment: By righ-hand side you mean b in Ax=b?, but I don't see how b would enter in the proof